# 3 horizontal lines navicon in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, mobile

I was unable to locate the menu navicon (3-line one) in jquery mobile.

The closest I can find is ui-icon-grid.

Is the navicon available at all in jquery mobile, or is there a different implementation available ?

Comment: Did anyone solve your problem? If so, could you please accept the best answer (click the checkmark under the points). That will help other users that come across your question quickly spot the accepted answer and it also gives 15 rep. points to the author (:

Answer (score 0):

Check this: [jQuery Mobile Icons](http://api.jquerymobile.com/icons/). I think it's `bars` (`ui-icon-bars`) what you are looking for.

If you need a wider variety of icons (font icons) Font Awesome may come in handy: [Font Awesome icons](http://fontawesome.io/icons/). Here it's called `fa-bars`.

**Edit:**

As Cindy pointed out, some font icons don't always display as desired, so in some cases using SVG will be the best option. [Here](http://css-tricks.com/icon-fonts-vs-svg/) there is a comparsion between SVG icons and font icons, beeing browser support and file size the main advantages of the latter.

Maybe this is a best solution (I haven't used it, but it looks good for me): [IcoMoon](http://icomoon.io/app/) lets you select just the icons you need (you also have the one you was asking for) and the format you want (font or SVG). Moreover, you can configure some other options like including PNG, including a SVG sprite, dimensions, color...).

Comment: I am looking for a 3-bar icon for menu.

Comment: Yes, it's called `bars` (`ui-icon-bars`). Check if it's the one that appears in the link under that name and if it's not maybe you can post an image so that we can see exactly what you mean.

Comment: Is it depends on versions of jquery mobile? Is it depends of browsers' versions?

Comment: I don't know if in previous versions there were different icons or maybe they were named differently, as happened with Font Awesome. Anyway, if that's the problem I would try to update the project to use the latest version. I don't think it depends on the browsers' versions unless you use a very old one. It would be more likely that you have some other CSS rules that are preventing the icons from showing up.

Comment: great, what is font awesome? is it commercial ?

Comment: Font Awesome is a set of font icons that you can use in different ways: using the CSS classes they provide or using the font directly as you would use any other font. The main advantage is that they are scalable (because they are vector graphics) and they come in a single font file, so only one HTTP request is needed to load them.
You can use it for commercial projects too: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/license/

Comment: fa-bars has uneven space between bars when font-size:100%, when expand thru control+, unevenness disappear ...

Comment: You can adjust the font-size to a value where there's no unevenness. However, that probably remains a problem for some icons, so maybe the best option for you is to use inline SVG icons, although you may have some problems with browser support (problems that can be avoided, with some extra work). It's up to you choosing one option or another. I update the answer with a comparison between the two options. It would be nice if you could vote the comments or answers that were useful to you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS for that:

Without image:

```
a {
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:50px;
    font-weight:700;
    display:inline-block;
    transform:rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(90deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
    /* Opera, Chrome, and Safari */
    color:white; //Change the color you want for your icon
    letter-spacing:-3px;
    height:34px;
    width:34px;
}
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/x6g7S/1/

With image:

```
#A_1 {
    height: 40px;
    left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 40px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABkAAAAZCAYAAADE6YVjAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAADhJREFUeNpi/P//PwOtARMDHQBdLGFBYtMq3BiHT3DRPU4YR4NrNAmPJuHRJDyahEeT8Ii3BCDAAF0WBj5Er5idAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC) no-repeat scroll 50% 50% / auto padding-box border-box;
    }
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/x6g7S/

Comment: That's the base64 encoding of the image.

Comment: i am lookng for svg image

Comment: Okay, how about without using any image? Check the updated answer.